# Is there any const std::string-alike class which computes hash on construction?

Tags: c++, string, hash, unordered-map

Does anyone know of a const std::string-alike class which computes the hash sum on construction, for use faster lookups?

*Update:*
Changed the question from handling mutable strings to what Caramiriel explained.

Comment: In order to update the key you would need to remove the pair and readd it. Otherwise it would need to know how to update unordered maps (or sets, or...). Updating the hash is one thing, but it would end up in the wrong buckets, thus would become unfindable.

Comment: Not in the Standard Library, no, and other-library recommendations are off-topic on S.O..  If you tried to implement it, had trouble and posted your code, that *would* be on topic.